# Unable to pass environment variables from makefile target to a bash file

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following `Makefile`:

```
my-file/config.json: check-envs
    ./my-script.sh

check-envs:
ifndef MY_VARIABLE
    $(error Variable MY_VARIABLE isn't set)
endif
ifndef MY_NAME
    $(error Variable MY_NAME isn't set)
endif

.PHONY: init-config
init-config: deps
init-config: export MY_VARIABLE=space-1
init-config: my-file/config.json

.PHONY: deps
deps:
    # install deps here
```

So I tried running `MY_NAME=example make init-config`, but `check-envs` target fails with the `MY_VARIABLE` being not set.

I've tried to change the logic to, for example, validate environment variables in `my-script.sh` but unfortunately the same result happens, I can't pass the environment variable to the script from the Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not really how makefiles work. They work per-target, so in target `init-config` you can set some stuff up, but it won't persist to another target.

You have some options:

1.) Set your variable in the makefile body (variables are evaluated before the targets are executed):

```
# Here
MY_VARIABLE = xyz

my-file/config.json: check-envs
    ./my-script.sh

check-envs:
ifndef MY_VARIABLE
    $(error Variable MY_VARIABLE isn't set)
endif
   :
  etc
   :
```

2.) Pass the variable in:

```
make some_target MY_VARIABLE=xyz
```

3.) Parse the arguments list

```
# Get all the makefile parameters (or arguments)
ALL_PARAMS = $(wordlist 1,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

# Test for your argument and set a variable accordingly
ifneq (,$(findstring my_param,$(ALL_PARAMS)))
  MY_VARIABLE=xzy
endif

# Empty rule so the my_param is not complained about as a missing target
my_param:;@;

my-file/config.json: check-envs
    ./my-script.sh

check-envs:
ifndef MY_VARIABLE
    $(error Variable MY_VARIABLE isn't set)
endif
   :
  etc
```

And then call like: `make my_param check-envs`

The last way, is a bit messy, but the results are quite good because it gives you make tab-completion instead of the horrbile passing in a variable.